# AngularJS: emulate ng-repeat scope creation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way in angular to emulate the same scoping  that ng-repeat creates without actually using ng-repeat?

An example structure is

```
<ul ng-controller="SomeController" ng-model="items">
     <li ng-model="item" static-item>static html</li>
     <li ng-model="item" static-item>static html</li>
</ul>
```

and then have similar scopes created as if I used an ng-repeat?

```
<ul ng-controller="SomeController" ng-model="items">
     <li ng-repeat="item in items">static html</li>
</ul>
```

Wherein properties created through iteration will still be available inside my staticItem directive (ie. $last, $first, $middle)?

I am using bootstrap angular directives (specifically tab component) which creates an isolated scope for each tab item. And the mark up is generated through CMS.

Comment: You can create a directive, but is it really worth it?

Comment: I am using bootstrap angular directives (specifically tab component) which creates an isolated scope for each tab item. And the mark up is generated through CMS.